# How can I make the Eject Key to behave as the Insert key?

Tags: keyboard

Is there any way to force that the Eject Key behaves as the Insert Key?

In particular I would like to be able to send the key combinations Ctrl+Insert and also Ctrl+Alt+Insert to the following two applications using Ctrl+Eject and Ctrl+Option+Eject:

a) A VMWare Fusion image
b) A RDP connection with CoRD or Microsoft RDC

Answer (score 1):

Remap the key using [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).